# How to ensure an unique item/object is picked from the collection in multi-threading scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a collection of string values available.

I thought of using `CopyOnwriteArrayList` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` initially. But, when I run my code, I see that same string values are picked by one more threads most of the time.

Here is my working code with the lock to serve the purpose:

```
public class SomeClass {

  ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  // this list is ensured to have non-duplicate items.
  private List<String> bookingIds;

  public String read() {
    lock.lock();
    if (Objects.isNull(bookingIds)) {
      bookingIds = bookingInfoUtil.findDistinctId();
    }
    if (! bookingIds.isEmpty()) {
      String bookingId = bookingIds.remove(0);
      lock.unlock();
      return bookingId;
    }
    lock.unlock();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to know how to achieve this with a lock-free mechanism, preferably with a thread-safe collection. As I mentioned above, I tried to use both `CopyOnwriteArrayList` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and exposed it to a threadpool that actively call `read()` method to obtain a unique value. It always fails to attain this goal unless a lock is used. Any better ways to do this?

Comment: Define "*without lock*". Do you mean "without an explicit lock", or do you also rule-out the semantics of [`synchroized` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) by this? --- How is but the form following the function of why. So: why do you want to eliminate the lock?

Comment: yes, should not be sequential and without an explicit lock.

Comment: I am afraid that we have to sequentialize at some point. Even data structures like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` sequentialize somehow.

Comment: okay, what if I don't want explicit lock and do not want synchronized (where one thread could indefinitely blocks) -- sequential is still okay, as long as I get unique values across threads.

Comment: "*... where one thread could indefinitely blocks...*" - Why do you think that one thread could indefinitely block?

Comment: Please provide `bookingInfoUtil.findDistinctId()` implementation

Comment: okay, is there better way than `synchronized` ?

Comment: @gdomo it's a database query -- Spring Data JPA query

Comment: Define "better". It all depends on what the actual problem is.

Comment: "better" -> Reentrantlock that I used the current code is much better than going with synchronized, although may not be too different. Problem statement is simple: distribute unique values (one item per thread) across all threads as quick as possible.

Comment: You can also consider using BlockingQueue - like LinkedBlockingQueue, its take() method will wait till the queue is non empty, or you can use pool() to get first element or get null if its empty. But, I am not sure if its initialization will be thread safe in you case.

Comment: "*"better" -> Reentrantlock that I used the current code is much better than going with synchronized*" - By what metric? Faster? Less overhead? Readability? "Better" is not a clear metric. Again: how is but the form, following the function of why. WHY do you want to get rid of the lock? What is the actual issue?

Comment: If you want to remove a synchronization, then you'll need to assure that _findDistinctId_ is going to return the qualifying, unique value, every time; which, seems almost impossible.  Can you provide more information, or possibly more code?

Comment: @Reilas `findDistinctId` is Spring Data JPA query that is guaranteed to return list of unique values. It is used just for initial loading.

Comment: @marcinj yup, thats nice thing to know. But, will I get the same value in multiple threads when we poll the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the approach that I used:

1. Moved the data loading logic of `bookingInfoUtil.findDistinctId()` , outside of `read()` so that data is populated before threads reach to `read()` method.
2. Since I'm modifying the list under multi-threading environment, I used a lock-free thread-safe queue, that is `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, so that my performance is much better for `insert/remove` operation. Also, it doesn't have to re-shuffle the entire list of elements since it is a queue.

So, the code is simplified to:

```
public class SomeClass {

  // Value is actually set as a batch job parameter for my case.
  // But, you can also set this as a bean or load the values using constructor.
  @Value("#{jobParameters[bookingIds]}")
  ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> bookingIds;

  public String read() {
    if (! bookingIds.isEmpty()) {
      return bookingIds.poll();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from "check and act" operation which is compound action and hence not "atomic".
So even if we use threadsafe concurrent collection and technically our collection is not breaking but the result is not what we would expect.

Compound action:If collection is null/empty then initialize,a similar to computeIfAbsent in Map

For better understanding refer "Java Concurrency In Practice" book's Building Blocks :Problems with synchronized collection section.

It is suggested and a good practice to use synchronization and/or explicit locking to do compound actions.
Since in requirement ,we wanted to avoid it somehow, we could go for a middle ground based on general usecase.

We could use lazy loading of values for better throughput performance and to avoid visibility issues making it volatile (optionally could have used AtomicReference).

```
public class SomeClass {

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private volatile ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> bookingIds = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public void initializeBookingIds() {
        lock.lock();
        try{
            if ( !bookingIds.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> bookingIdsList = bookingInfoUtil.findDistinctId();
                bookingIds =  new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(bookingIdsList); 
            }
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public String read() {
        
        if (!bookingIds.isEmpty()) {
            initializeBookingIds();
        }
        return bookingIds.poll();
    }
}
```

In above code we are directly returning poll value since we are good with null if not found and ofcouse wanted to avoid compound action.

The above code is far from robust and could fail in scenario with unlucky timing.

- t1 acquires lock,initializes list with only 1 element for example and is about to release lock at line 15
- t2 is checking if bookingIds is empty at line 21
- t2 consumes the element and returns
- t1 releases lock at 15
- t1 reaches at line 24 and returns null

Here even though t1 was the one which initialized the list, it was not able to consume the element.

With the given use case and based on general heuristics, the frequency of occurrence of this scenario is less as long as bookingInfoUtil returns a huge list.